# Failing to run jar file from command line: “no main manifest attribute”

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to run a jar file from the console:

```
java -jar ScrumTimeCaptureMaintenence.jar
```

And am getting the error:

> Can't execute jar- file: “no main manifest attribute”

As you can see I do in fact have a main file and it runs fine from eclipse:

[image: main method is in class]

What do I need to do to successfully run this file from the command line?

Comment: You need a `manifest` file with a `Main` entry.

Comment: Is there a way to generate one on jar export in eclipse?

Comment: If you export as a jar auto-executable, it will create the manifest for you

Comment: @DavidTunnell If you step through the Export wizard, there should be an option to specify a `Main` class.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try to run

```
java -cp ScrumTimeCaptureMaintenence.jar Main
```

Comment: If your class name is "Main" and package name is "com.mycompay" then the command will be like:
`java -cp /the_jar_file_path/the_jar_file.jar com.mycompay.Main`

Comment: when I am running this, it says `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:Path` is there any reason?

Answer (score 29):

In Eclipse: `right-click` on your project -> `Export` -> `JAR file`

At last page with options (when there will be no `Next` button active) you will see settings for `Main class:`. You need to set here class with `main` method which should be executed by default (like when JAR file will be double-clicked).

Comment: Been looking for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

The `-jar` option only works if the JAR file is an executable JAR file, which means it must have a manifest file with a `Main-Class` attribute in it.

If it's not an executable JAR, then you'll need to run the program with something like:

```
java -cp app.jar com.somepackage.SomeClass
```

where `com.somepackage.SomeClass` is the class that contains the `main` method to run the program.

Comment: Ah, after struggle of four hours : works in 2022,

Comment: Glad it helped! I remember I posted this answer because I too struggled for hours before finding this.

Answer (score 7):

First run your application from eclipse to create launch configuration.
Then just follow the steps:

> 1. From the menu bar's **File** menu, select **Export**.
> 2. Expand the **Java** node and select **Runnable JAR file**. Click **Next**.
> 3. In the 
>              
>              **Runnable JAR File Specification** page, select a 'Java Application' launch configuration to use to create a
>      runnable JAR.
> 4. In the **Export destination** field, either type or click **Browse** to select a location
>              for the JAR file.
> 5. Select an appropriate **library
>      handling** strategy.
> 6. Optionally, you can also create an ANT script to quickly regenerate a previously created runnable JAR file.

Source: [Creating a New Runnable JAR File](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-37.htm) at Eclipse.org

Answer (score 7):

You can select the "Runnable JAR File" after you click on "Export".

You can specify your main driver in "Launch Configuration"

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Export you Java Project as an **Runnable Jar file** rather than Jar.

I exported my project as **Jar** and even though the Manifest was present it gave me the error **no main manifest attribute in jar** even though the Manifest file was present in the Jar.  However there is only one entry in the Manifest file and it didn't specify the Main class or Function to execute or any dependent JAR's

After exporting it as **Runnable Jar file** it works as expected.

Comment: I had the same problems - adding Manifest didn't help. Runnable jar did. +1

Answer (score 2):

You need to include "Main class" attribute in Manisfest.mf file in Jar

For example: Main-Class: MyClassName

Second thing, To add Manifest file in Your jar, You can manually create file in your workspace folder, and refresh in Eclipse Project explorer.

While exporting, Eclipse will create a Jar which will include your manifest.

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring boot, you should add this plugin in your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```