# Can we run a Jar file of Selenium WebDriver code from Linux terminal? How?

Tags: linux, selenium, jar, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

When I tried to do so with command `java -jar samplewebdrivercode.jar` then I found Manifest error.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: You need to edit your question and add the entire stacktrace.

Comment: Error I am getting : "no main manifest attribute, in sample.jar"

Comment: This is the only line I am getting in terminal "no main manifest attribute, in sample.jar"

Comment: can you try this - `java -cp samplewebdrivercode.jar Main`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failing to run jar file form command line: “no main manifest attribute”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250966/failing-to-run-jar-file-form-command-line-no-main-manifest-attribute)

Comment: @ LittlePanda: Thanks for reply

 I tried with "java -cp samplewebdrivercode.jar Main" but it displays the error : "Could not find or load main class Main"

I have only single class in my code "SCPerformingTests"

Answer (score 1):

Your file does not conform to the requirements of [jar executable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html)

Which should have an manifest file with `Main-Class` attribute if you want to run with `-jar` option.

Alternatively you can run the jar by specifying the class path with `-cp` or `-classpath` option, where the class should have an entry point i.e. main method.

The call can be done like this
`java -classpath app.jar your.package.name.MainClass`

Comment: Hi Deimus, I am getting this errror "Could not find or load main class mycassname"

Comment: @PravinWare Specify your class name i.e. `SCPerformingTests`, altough its name sounds strange.