# no main manifest attribute, when trying to run a jar file

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to run this Java GUI application but I'm not sure how to get it to run. The project is located here: https://gitee.com/gangshushu/v7/tree/master/admon_gui/one-jar.
My initial attempt was:

`java -jar one-jar-ant-task-0.97.jar`

But I end up with the error:

> no main manifest attribute, in one-jar-ant-task-0.97.jar

Doing some search around, [Failing to run jar file from command line: “no main manifest attribute”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250966/failing-to-run-jar-file-from-command-line-no-main-manifest-attribute), I ended up running:

`java -cp one-jar-ant-task-0.97.jar Main`

But I end up with another error message:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Main
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main

Searching around gave me some information overload here: [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

How do I run this Java program? This is my first time trying to run a *jar* file, and I'm a little stuck.
Am I trying to run the Java program the wrong way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)

Comment: Given the name, it seems to be an ant-task, to be run from an Ant build script, it is not an executable program. It is unclear to me why you think this is an executable program.

Answer (score 0):

Your main class is in a package, you need to specify in what package to find your main class. Try the following command line:
`java -cp one-jar-ant-task-0.97.jar com.beegfs.admon.gui.program.Main`

Comment: Is there a default location where the main class lives? Running the command results in ```Error: Could not find or load main class com.beegfs.admon.gui.program.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beegfs.admon.gui.program.Main
```

Comment: Is that the main class you were trying to run? Is your main class packaged in the Jar? If you need to check, rename your jar as a zip and open with a zip tool.

Comment: No need to rename the file and use a _zip_ tool. The [jar](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jar.html#GUID-51C11B76-D9F6-4BC2-A805-3C847E857867) tool can also list the contents of a JAR file. And by the way, [WinRAR](https://www.win-rar.com/start.html?&L=0) can also display contents of a JAR file without the need to rename the file.

Comment: I unzipped it and there doesn't seem to be a Main file. Although it does have other java files